# Human body measurements dataset

Tags: data-request

I'm doing research on good ways to take measurements in order to make a match between someone's morphology and a garment.

As I don't have the resources do tests in the field, I'd like to use a dataset of containing basic human body measurements (height, weight, chest, waist) for a diversified population.

Do you know about any good resources I could use to do such a work?

**EDIT**: I noticed how my question lacked of precision. So ideally the dataset would contain as basic information:

- Height
- Weight
- Neck size
- Chest size
- Waist size

for adult men and women.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Publicly Available Datasets](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/155/publicly-available-datasets)

Comment: Maybe you could look into some medical or antropological data. (Though that's very much not my field of expertise)

Comment: You may want to look at this question on age, height, weight datasets: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7793/age-weight-and-height-dataset/

Comment: Are you interested in the dependencies of the variables or could you treat the variables as independent random variables and get by with normal distributions for each variable?

Comment: @Grimaldi I'm interest in the dependencies of the variables. How they relate to each other and if it is possible to predict one feature from the others, how precise would it be and how many features are required to get a decent result.

Comment: i currently want to work on a personal similar and i wanted to have a chat with you pls @WitoldW or anybody. thank you

Comment: I'm currently working on something very similar to yours and would love to get some pointers... Were you able to make progress in your project?

Answer (score 4):

You probably need an "antropometric dataset", like [this one](http://www.nuffieldfoundation.org/fsmqs/level-3-data-analysis#Anthropometric%20data) (Student data (1.8 MB) ).

Comment: Thank you, ! Interesting data but it is not exactly what I'm looking for. I edited my question to be more precise.