# Height and Age - Children and Adults

Tags: data-request, medical

I would like to get height and age data for individuals *of all ages*. 
This previous question [Age, Weight and Height dataset](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7793/14851)
Lists several datasets for adults and a dataset for children. Google shows a few others that are also either all children or all adults. But I specifically want to look at the shift from the growth years to non-growth as an adult. Of course, I could combine data sets, but it is not obvious that the populations from different surveys would be comparable. Is there a single data set that covers both children and adults?

Comment: Do you mean growth data for the same individuals? aka [Longitudinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_study)?

Comment: No,  population data.  Not for the same individual. Also not summary statistics with means by age.  I want data for individuals of all ages.