# Various sources for self-reported heights of adults

Tags: data-request, medical, demographics, global

I'm looking for various sources (Global: US, UK, Europe) of adult height data. And it should be self-reported (meaning the person reports their own height, and not that a doctor measures them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has a relevant answer on this forum: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12085/1511

https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer

And the data even has a weird distribution (big bar at 182-185 cm, which contains 6 feet 0 inches):

[image]

and another one with two peaks

[image]

https://www.kaggle.com/stefanoleone992/fifa-20-complete-player-dataset

But I can't be sure it's self-reported.